# Today Extension: How to work with display mode?

Tags: xcode, swift, expand, today-extension, ios10

> Widgets now include the concept of display mode (represented by [NCWidgetDisplayMode](https://developer.apple.com/reference/notificationcenter/ncwidgetdisplaymode)), which lets you describe how much content is available and allows users to choose a compact or expanded view.

How to expand widget in ios 10.0? It doesn't work as in ios 9.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Ok, i found right solution [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/144158#144158).

1) Set the display mode to `NCWidgetDisplayMode.expanded` first in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = NCWidgetDisplayMode.expanded
}
```

2) Implement new protocol method:

```
func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {
    if (activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayMode.compact) {
        self.preferredContentSize = maxSize
    }
    else {
        //expanded
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: maxSize.width, height: 200)
    }
}
```

And it will work as official apps.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nto0Q.jpg)

Comment: I'm trying this so that I can set the widget to the height of my table view but it always comes through to the widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange as .compact even though I set the extensionContext to expanded.  Any ideas why display mode isn't being set?

Comment: The `viewDidLoad` snippet doesn't set the mode to `.expanded`, it just makes it available (the default is `.compact` -only.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a Objective-C one.

```
- (void)widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange:(NCWidgetDisplayMode)activeDisplayMode
                         withMaximumSize:(CGSize)maxSize
{
    if (activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayModeCompact) {
        self.preferredContentSize = maxSize;
    }
    else {
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 200);
    }
}
```