# Today Widget is too big on devices that are on lower IOS than 10

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, today-extension

I have problem that the today extension is way too big on IOS versions lower that 9. But it is exactly how I want on greater or equal to IOS 10 devices. And also it is misplaced on the IOS 9 devices.

The constraints I have are the following:

1. Center vertically,
2. Center horizontally,
3. Fixed height(200),
4. Fixed width(200)

This is how it looks on IOS10+

[image]

And it looks like this on IOS9

[image]

What could cause the issue?

Comment: Maybe trying [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39936934/size-problems-by-converting-ios-9-today-extension-to-ios-10) can help you

Comment: According to that page, `self.preferredContentSize.height = 200` should be used to set the height in iOS 9

Comment: Ohh.. you are totally right. I missed the else block :) But still, why it is not centered?

Comment: Then maybe you should set the width smaller... I don't really know

Comment: I had also some issues with the layout (programmatically created) of a view in a today extension. I don't know if it will help in this case, but you can try it to setup your constraints in `viewDidAppear(_:)` instead of `viewDidLoad()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761157/today-extension-with-uicollectionview-different-behaviour-compared-to-single-vie

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**For iOS-8 and iOS-9**

```
func widgetMarginInsets(forProposedMarginInsets defaultMarginInsets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIEdgeInsets
{
    return UIEdgeInsets.zero
}
```

**For iOS-10**

It is handled automatically.

For more refer to: https://github.com/pgpt10/Today-Widget

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was creating a widget in ios 11 and couldn't seem to get my ios 9 widget centered correctly, even though I added all the necessary constraints.