# extensionContext have different spec in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, widget

I'm working on the implementation of a Today Widget for IOS in Swift (v2.2).

Following what i found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37995859/today-extension-how-to-work-with-display-mode) should be pretty easy to implement the "Display more" button for my widget, as the native ones.

I don't understand why xcode complains:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'NCWidgetDisplayMode'

I try even to change using `.expanded`, but seems that `extensionContext` have no method `widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode` and for instance i don't have even `open` but i have `openURL` instad.

The specific i'm taking a look is this one:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsextensioncontext

Am i looking in the wrong place? What i miss?

Thank you

Comment: Have you added `import NotificationCenter` to the top of your file and targeting iOS 10 and up?

Comment: the import yes, how can i check the targeting? The version of xcode can be related to the issue? I'm using 7.3.1 atm

Comment: Yes, if you're still on swift 2.2 you are likely not running Xcode 8.0, which means you're not developing for iOS 10.0+. So you won't see this API because it is new to iOS 10.